# Three.js - Connection particles with lines - How to make more effecient?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I was playing with Three.js and I was trying to make something like this https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/824319 This was made with p5 and is 2d.

I was trying to implement an extra method in the Boid class's method `update()` the code I was playing with is from https://github.com/juanuys/boids, with a live demo at https://juanuys.com/boids/

This is my first attempt

```
drawConnections(delta, neighbours) {

    neighbours.forEach(neighbour => {

        // skip same object
        if (neighbour.id === this.id) return;

        const distance = neighbour.mesh.position.distanceTo(this.mesh.position)

        let range = 50;

        if (distance <= range) {

            if (!this.connections) {

                this.connections = {};

                this.connections.material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(
                    {
                        color: 0xffffff,
                        linewidth: 3 //? not working?
                    }
                );
            }

            if (!this.connections[neighbour.id]) {

                this.connections[neighbour.id] = {};
                this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

                this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry.vertices.push(neighbour.mesh.position );
                this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry.vertices.push(this.mesh.position);

                this.connections[neighbour.id].line = new THREE.Line(this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry, this.connections.material);

                this.scene.add(this.connections[neighbour.id].line);

            } else {

                this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry.vertices[ 0 ].set(neighbour.mesh.position );
                this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry.vertices[ 1 ].set(this.mesh.position );

                this.connections[neighbour.id].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

            }

        } else { // neighbour not in range
            this.connections == null; // or hide somehow until back in range?
        }

    })
}
```

But it's extremely inefficient, plus it's not working as it should. It even deletes the Boids themselves :)

Do you have any pointers on how to make the code more effecient?

Comment: Write your line vertices into a large buffergemoetry to render them all in 1 draw call.

Comment: @manthrax, thanks. I'll look into that

Comment: You can look at the source code [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=draw#webgl_buffergeometry_drawrange). It seems pretty efficient.

Comment: @Marquizzo, wow. That is spot on! Thanks.